# How can I show list of groups with count of the group's participants with the groups in social media app?

Tags: node.js

I am working on a social media react-native app with Node JS in the backend having approx 1 million users.
I have to show a list of suggested groups to the user with the total members in the group.
Currently, I am using a count query that is taking time to calculate the total members each time.
What should I do to optimize this API or scenario?

Answer (score 1):

That's a good Question. First approach is add a column in each table. 2nd approach is create a new table of count. In count table save all the counts of the app. 3rd approach is using the DB cache or backend cache.